# alternate method for loop

Tags: html, reactjs, for-loop, dom

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import rangy from "rangy";
export default function Section() {
  const [load, setload] = useState(false);
  const [range, setrange] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    sort();
    setload(false);
  }, [load]);

  let sort = () => {
    try {
      let el = document.getElementById("root");
      let tea = el.querySelectorAll("*[id]");
      let spl = [],
        fl = [],
        m = -1,
        z = -1,
        n = -1;
      //getting all the ids named section
      for (let i = 0; i < tea.length; i++) {
        let y = tea[i].id.split("");
        if (y[0] === "s" && y[1] === "e" && y[2] === "c") {
          m++;
          spl[m] = tea[i].id;
        }
      }
      //getting no. from the section nane
      for (let j = 0; j < spl.length; j++) {
        let x = spl[j].split("_");
        n++;
        fl[n] = +x[1];
      }
      //sorting
      fl.sort();

  //changing section name
  for (let i = 0; i < tea.length; i++) {
    let y = tea[i].id.split("");
    if (y[0] === "s" && y[1] === "e" && y[2] === "c") {
      z++;
      tea[i].id = "section_" + fl[z];
    }
  }
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}


 };

  let getFirstrange = () => {
    let sel = rangy.getSelection();
    return sel.rangeCount ? sel.getRangeAt(0) : null;
  };

  let main = (e) => {
    try {
      let ids = range.commonAncestorContainer.parentNode.id;
      let cn = range.commonAncestorContainer.parentNode.className;
      if (cn === "par") {
        alert("already wrapped");
      } else {
        let el = document.getElementById(ids);
        let nl = document.createElement("div");
        nl.className = "section";
        nl.id = e;
        let al = document.createElement("div");
        al.id = ids;
        al.className = "par";
        al.innerHTML = `${el.textContent}`;
        al.onclick = () => {
          let run = getFirstrange();
          setrange(run);
        };
        nl.append(al);
        el.after(nl);
        el.remove();
        let x = document.getElementById("select");
        for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
          if (x[i].value === e) {
            x[i].remove();
          }
        }
        setload(true);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <div id="names">
        <select
          name="sec"
          onChange={(e) => {
            main(e.target.value);
          }}
          id="select"
        >
          <option value="section" selected>
            section
          </option>
          <option value="section_1">section1</option>
          <option value="section_2">section2</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div
        className="ne"
        id="key1"
        onClick={() => {
          let run = getFirstrange();
          setrange(run);
        }}
      >
        Mohamed Salah Hamed Mahrous Ghaly is an Egyptian professional footballer
        who plays as a forward for Premier League club Liverpool and captains
        the Egypt national team. Considered one of the best players in the
        world, he is known for his finishing, dribbling, and speed.
      </div>
      <div
        className="ne"
        id="key2"
        onClick={() => {
          let run = getFirstrange();
          setrange(run);
        }}
      >
        Kevin De Bruyne is a Belgian professional footballer who plays as a
        midfielder for Premier League club Manchester City and the Belgium
        national team. De Bruyne is widely regarded as one of the best players
        in the world, and has often been described as a "complete footballer".
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

i get the correct neat result. but i need to optimze the **sort()** (11th line)function cause i was told to use other methods like MRF ,foreach and so on.is there any other method to do the **sort()** (11th line)function?..I tried using filter but i came to learn that filter method is 75% slower than for loop. and map method is not needed for that place. i have a little knowledge about the reduce method. so plz suggest me some other methods if there any ..

Comment: Your code example is rather large, and it's not immediately clear what each `for` loop is intended for. Please provide more context about what they are for, and how it's working (or not) for you. The easier you make it for the community to understand your code, the better chance you'd have for getting the helpful answer, quicker.

Comment: Also, I wouldn't worry about optimizing for performance gains at this point and focus on getting the functionality right. JavaScript `Array` has quite a few built-in methods (e.g. `.every`, `.sort`, `.filter`, `.find`, `forEach`, `.reduce`, etc)—each of which meant for specific common use cases—and their intuitive APIs and code readability is very much worth it. Not knowing what each of your `for` loops is doing, it's hard to provide further answer. I'd start with this [MDN page about Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)